# Injecting Stateless EJB into Named Bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

following a tutorial and got stuck with an issue.
System: wildfly 10, maven project with multimodules, packaging: ear

EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class ToyService implements ToyServiceRemote, ToyServiceLocal {
...
}
```

INTERFACE:

```
@Local
public interface ToyServiceLocal {
...
}
```

BEAN:

```
@Named("toyProducts")
@RequestScoped
public class ProductBean {

    @Inject
    private ToyServiceLocal toyService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
       toyList = toyService.getAllToys();
    }
    ...
}
```

JSF:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{toyProducts.toyList}" var="toy">
...
</ui:repeat>
```

The application deploys, but when I try to open the page in browser I am getting:

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-62) UT005023: Exception
>   handling request to /index.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: Can
>   not set com.example.common.service.ToyServiceLocal field
>   shop.beans.ProductBean.toyService to
>   com.example.product.service.ToyServiceLocal$ToyServiceRemote$1303029808$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
>   wildfly-experiment |  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   wildfly-experiment |  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   wildfly-experiment |  at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "real" answer this time: since I am using multi module maven project, packaged as EAR (with some EJBs, a common JAR and the WAR file). All I had to do was to add scope provided in the WAR file (common is JAR and product in EJB)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>product</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Then please remove your other answer